# Inserting data in a pivot table via a macro

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

The intention is to copy dynamically the complete range of data from page `INPUT` to the pivot table `Table16` on page `OUTPUT` - in the first cell under the title `NAME`.

*A small remark in the pivot table (some kind of template) contains more columns then just the 3 I want to copy in.*

```
Sub SelectCopy()
 '
 ' SelectCopy Macro
 '

' the intention is to copy dynamically  the complete range of data - on page INPUT
 ' to the pivot table Table16 on OUTPUT page - in the first cel under the title NAME

Range_cels = Sheets("info").Range("M4").Value

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("input").Select

     Range(Range_cels).Select
     Selection.Copy

      MsgBox "The data has been successfully copied."

     ThisWorkbook.Sheets("output").Select
     '1/
     'table16 is a pivot table, wanted select the first cell beneath the title row
     ' complains about 'ActiveSheet.Paste' failure
     ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Range("Table16[[#Headers],[Name]]").Select
     '2/ - works fine but puts it in the last selected cell
     'ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=0).Activate
     '3/ - fails complains it is in pivot table
     'Range("A2").Select

      MsgBox "almost ... pasted."

     ActiveSheet.Paste

      MsgBox "The data has been successfully pasted."
      MsgBox "The data has been successfully copied & pasted."

End Sub
```

[image]

**Method 1:**

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Range("Table16[[#Headers],[Name]]").Select
```

Gives error 1004:

[image]

This is the pivot table:

[image]

Comment: **@pnuts** when I do several rows it is not a problem.
But when I do the _complete_ range ... _the problem occurs_.
So maybe I have to look ... for a loop over the rows of the range

Comment: @pnuts How do you mean?